# Shutil copy2 says it copied the files, but I can't actually see them in Windows explorer

Tags: python, windows, copy

```py
def do_it():
    global files_to_move
    global copymove

    for file_dict in files_to_move.values():
        if check_path(file_dict['new_path']) == False:
            return
        
        if (file_dict['disabled']):
            continue

        new_name = file_dict['new_path']+'\\'+file_dict['new_name']
        if os.path.exists(new_name):
            status_update(f"Error! the file we were going to move already exists? {new_name}")
            continue
        try:
            if copymove == 'MOVE':
                os.rename(file_dict['path_file'], new_name)
                status_update(f"Moved {file_dict['path_file']} to { new_name}")
            else:
                shutil.copy2(file_dict['path_file'], new_name)
                status_update(f"Copied {file_dict['path_file']} to { new_name}")

        except OSError as e:
            status_update(f'Error renaming file: {e}')
    update_files()
    return
```

Using the above code, I have a listing of files (a dict of file information including name, path, newname, etc) that I want to copy from the old location to the new location. When I run this, it seems to work and says that the files are copied. However, they don't actually show in Windows explorer on my computer so I would assume it failed.

However, when I update the file listing, it detects the files when I do os.listdir(path). Somehow it's detecting files that weren't copied. And if I run the operation again (which detects collisions and renames the files before copy to accomodate), I end up with duplicate phantom files. What is going on!?

How do I make the file copy actually complete? What should I be using in my code instead to make this work?

Comment: In checking a cmd prompt, the files are PRESENT and show when doing a directory command, but STILL do not show in Explorer. Somehow Shutil secretly copied them to this other computer and they're imperceptable. Great if I want to get into hacking, but kind of crappy when I'm trying to manage my home photos.

Comment: Attempted os.system() call to copy - no effect - didn't even copy the file.

Answer (score 0):

After resting on it and coming back with some manual copy commands to test a given source file and destination, I realized there's an error in my path. It turns out GD windows renames the photos folder to "pictures" on the fly because it has to be special - the ACTUAL path is "photos" and I was creating and copying to a folder next to it called "pictures" (because that's what it shows in Windows Explorer).